# PHP Input MS SQL Failed to convert date and/or time from character string

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm running a MSSQL function and returning to PHP and I'm using the function twice in the PHP and writing it away to a MySQL database.

The first time I run the function I'm using $to and $from (I'm well aware it's not pretty, I'm not a php coder by trade...)

```
$to = date("j M Y", mktime());
$year = date("Y", mktime());
$jan = '1 jan ';
$from = $jan . $year;
```

I'm then using the following

```
select * from MISYearToDate('$from', '$to')
```

and that works absolutely fine.

When I then do the same thing but putting in this week's dates using

```
$weekstarting = date('j M Y', strtotime('last sunday'))."<br>";
$weekending = date('j M Y', strtotime('next saturday'))."<br>";
```

and then run

```
select * from MISYearToDate('$weekstarting', '$weekending')
```

I'm getting the error

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. )
```

$From and $to echo

```
1 jan 2012
27 Jun 2012
```

$weekstarting and $weekending echo

```
24 Jun 2012
30 Jun 2012
```

So as far as I can tell, there really isn't a difference and I'm pretty damn confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$weekending = date('j M Y', strtotime('next saturday'))."<br>";
                                                       ^^^^^^^
```

`<br>` is not a valid component of an SQL date string. You're probably viewing the output in a browser, so the `<br>` is effectively hidden, but that's where your problem is.

That's turning your query into:

```
select * from MISYearToDate('24 Jun 2012<br>', '30 Jun 2012<br>')
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest things... That will teach me to try to combine 2 tasks in one line of code :D

Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I'd suggest always doing a 'view source' anytime you're debugging PHP output in a browser, especially if you're mixing html with your data - the browser will essentially lie to you, because it doesn't know you'e debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend only feeding dates into SQL in the format of yyyy-mm-dd. This will ensure SQL doesn't get confused with the date format.

SQL will not accept dates in the format of 1 jan 2012 (as a string).

Comment: So, just for my knowledge, how come it accepted the $from and $to strings?

Comment: Also, I'm no longer getting the message, however I am getting very different results returning in SSMS and PHP...

e.g. in PHP I'm getting "Bob Nudd 0 0 0 0" whereas in SSMS I'm getting "Bob Nudd 1 5 23 15"